# Spring JPA repository method query name for between

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to fetch the records for which either `updated` Date or `created` Date lie between a date range. 
The entity class is like below:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

  @Id
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  private String orderId;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
  private Date created;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
  private Date updated;

}
```

The repository on it is below:

```
public interface OrderRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
  public Page<Order> findByCreatedBetweenOrUpdatedBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate,
      Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

Issue is when I use this, I get below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available
>   for part updated BETWEEN (2): [IsBetween, Between] NEVER.     at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116)   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:56)

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide 4 dates.

First two for the Create Between and second two for the Updated Between:

```
public interface OrderRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
  public Page<Order> findByCreatedBetweenOrUpdatedBetween(
           Date startDateCreated, Date endDateCreated
         , Date startDateUpdated, Date endDateUpdated
         , Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

Comment: I did consider that option, but for that I'll have to pass each date twice. Seems a bit redundant. Is there anyway I can pass just 2 dates.

Comment: This is the way the engine works. It expects a a parameter (or set in this case) for each keyword used.

Comment: @iCode you could just add a default method to `OrderRepository` that delegates to the generated one and takes care of duplicating the dates

Comment: Or you could just define the query manually using the `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Write the `findByCreatedBetweenOrUpdatedBetween` method signature as below.

```
public interface OrderRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
  public Page<Order> findByCreatedBetweenOrUpdatedBetween(Date startDate1, Date endDate1,
      Date startDate2, Date endDate2, Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto generation is fine for simple queries: in this case is probably easier just to define the query manually then you only need 2 parameters.

```
public interface OrderRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Order> {

  @Query("select o from Order o where (o.startDate between ?1 and ?2) " + 
            "or (o.updatedDate between ?1 and ?2)")
  public Page<Order> findByCreatedOrUpdatedBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate,
      Pageable pageRequest);
}
```